# tinymce.d.ts of TinyMCE 6 had an error compiling

Tags: angular, typescript, tinymce-6

I'm using the TinyMCE 4 library and want to upgrade to TinyMCE 6. I downloaded the self-hosted version and replaced it in the assets folder.

When I run `ng serve` I get the error as below

```
$./node_modules/.bin/ng serve
** NG Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
Date: 2023-11-23T00:53:00.706Z                                                          
Hash: fc2dbbadf762b0533697
Time: 18711ms
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js (inline) 5.79 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js (main) 4.96 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js (polyfills) 1.54 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js (styles) 64.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js (vendor) 12.4 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (1404,42): Cannot find name 'ReferrerPolicy'.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (26,27): ',' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (36,68): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2123,12): ',' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2125,14): ',' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2153,34): ',' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2161,26): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2161,45): '(' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2161,51): ',' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2161,62): ')' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2205,32): ',' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2219,78): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2219,97): '(' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2219,99): Property or signature expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2219,103): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2220,12): '>' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2220,30): ')' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2220,53): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2220,62): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2220,63): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2221,5): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2223,61): '=>' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2224,93): '=>' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2226,103): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2227,80): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2228,57): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2229,107): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2230,110): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2237,60): '(' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2239,40): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2240,35): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2242,64): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2243,67): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2244,84): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2245,48): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2246,48): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2249,64): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2251,70): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2255,12): '>' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2255,30): ')' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2255,50): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2255,65): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2255,66): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2256,12): '>' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2256,30): ')' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2256,47): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2256,58): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2256,73): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2256,74): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2256,101): '(' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2259,12): '>' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2259,32): ')' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2259,46): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2259,70): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2259,79): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2259,80): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2260,12): '>' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2260,32): ')' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2260,46): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2260,63): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2260,78): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2260,87): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2260,88): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2263,12): '>' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2263,26): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2263,52): ')' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2263,67): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2263,70): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2263,71): Declaration or statement expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2264,46): '=>' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2267,14): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2267,32): ')' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2267,47): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2267,62): ';' expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2267,86): Expression expected.
ERROR in <Angular project path>/src/assets/tinymce/js/tinymce/tinymce.d.ts (2267,91): ';' expected.
...
...
webpack: Failed to compile.
```

This does not happen with TinyMCE 4.x. The file tinymce.d.ts only appears in the TinyMCE 5+ package

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "igniteui-angular2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/IgniteUI/igniteui-angular2.git"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~4.0.0",
    "@ngui/sortable": "^0.4.1",
    "@types/encoding-japanese": "^1.0.15",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "encoding-japanese": "^1.0.26",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "formBuilder": "^2.5.3",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ngx-loading": "^1.0.14",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "toastr": "^2.1.4",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-optimizer": "0.0.32",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "0.0.35",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.0",
    "@ngtools/json-schema": "^1.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.8.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^0.1.2",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.2.10",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.46",
    "@types/reflect-metadata": "^0.0.5",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "coveralls": "^2.11.9",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.19",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage": "",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.4.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.5.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "traceur": "^0.0.111",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm prune",
    "start": "npm run lite",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "watch": "node node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc -w",
    "build": "node node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc",
    "build-aot": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "build-aot-samples": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot-samples.json",
    "bundle": "npm run build-aot && npm run prepare-dist",
    "prepare-dist": "cp src/igniteui.angular2.js dist/npm/index.js  && cp src/igniteui.angular2.d.ts dist/npm/index.d.ts && cp src/igniteui.angular2.metadata.json dist/npm/index.metadata.json && cp src/igniteui.angular2.ts dist/npm/igniteui.angular2.ts && cp src/igniteui.ts dist/npm/ && cp src/igniteui.js dist/npm/ && cp src/igniteui.js.map dist/npm/ && cp src/jquery.d.ts dist/npm/",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "karma start tests/karma.conf.js && npm run remap-istanbul",
    "remap-istanbul": "npm run copy-coverage-report && npm run remap-istanbul-html && npm run remap-istanbul-lcov",
    "remap-istanbul-html": "remap-istanbul -i coverage/karma-tmp/coverage.json -o coverage/html-report -t html",
    "remap-istanbul-lcov": "remap-istanbul -i coverage/karma-tmp/coverage.json -o coverage/lcov.info -t lcovonly",
    "copy-coverage-report": "cp coverage/karma-tmp/**/coverage*.json coverage/karma-tmp/"
  }
}
```

Is the cause because my typescript version is too old? Or is it due to the version of Node and Angular?

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 20.10.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 4.0.3
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router, upgrade

@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.32
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.20
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.35
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.2
typescript: 2.1.6
webpack: 3.8.1
```